# What do the stagger icons mean?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

So when I stagger an enemy a small icon appears on their status bar which seems to be related to the stagger condition as it's got a small wave underneath it.

What do these icons mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Referring to this wiki page](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Stagger#Lightning_Returns:_Final_Fantasy_XIII), they have the following meanings.

[image: Stagger icons]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which monster you've staggered, and how you went about it.  The icon you get is a standard debuff icon; it's not specific to the stagger, and can also be applied if you have the corresponding skill.

For example, there's one mech, which can be staggered with either magic or physical attacks.  Depending on which you use, it gains the *opposite* debuff.  So you can use that to plan out how you're going to kill it.